# Saddle valve won't turn off

Tags: plumbing, shutoff

Can you actually turn off a saddle valve to replace a refrigerator and then turn it back on?

Comment: General tip: if the nearest shutoff doesn’t work, turn off the whole house. Open an exterior hose bib to drain.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, unless the saddle valve is corroded. Then it won't turn off completely and afterwards possibly won't open back up.  If it's really corroded you might not even be able to turn it at all.